# What are the differences between IIS on Windows 7 Pro/Ultimate and the version of IIS in Server 2008?

Tags: windows-server-2008, windows-7, iis-7

I have some Windows Server 2008 hosting on which I intend to build my new personal web site. However, the problem I have is that I can't get hold of a copy of Server 2008 to develop on, without buying the full version (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1516037/windows-server-2008-is-there-some-kind-of-developer-edition)).

My question is, can I develop against the IIS which comes with Windows 7 and will it support all the features of the 'proper' IIS 7 on Server 2008? I'm aware the Win 7 version will have limitations, like only supporting a single site (I assume); I just want to know will it support URL rewriting, authentication, caching etc.

Hope you can help me out!

Cheers, 
Mark

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Windows 7 comes with IIS7.5 - the same version as in Server 2008 R2. Now, there's not much difference from IIS7 but this might be good to know because there's likely to be some differences - like how the app pool identity stuff works? (failed to find a nice list atm) Vista and the old Server 2008 comes with IIS7... though I think there's a rollup for IIS7 which provides much of the same functionality?

Answer (score 1):

In earlier IIS/OS versions the only difference was the inability to create multiple sites. But that limitation doesn't exist in Win7/IIS7.5.

It appears there is no difference, other than the maximum 10 clients EULA restriction.